# Android: is it possible to use Push notification from and admin app

Tags: android, push-notification

i have a client app and admin app to add product or edit them, i want to add an activity with edittext for admin to add a phone numb or user ID to send a Push notification with content Admin would write himself to the specific phone numb.

Iam using firebase realtime Database with phone Auth

is it possible? and how exactly to do so?

Answer (score 0):

if your app server implements the XMPP Connection Server protocol, it can receive upstream messages from a user's device to the cloud. To initiate an upstream message, the client app sends a request containing the following:

The address of the receiving app server in the format SENDER_ID@fcm.googleapis.com.
A message ID that should be unique for each sender ID.
The message data comprising the key-value pairs of the message's payload.
When it receives this data, FCM builds an XMPP stanza to send to the app server, adding some additional information about the sending device and app.

Send an upstream message from an Android client app

```
    FirebaseMessaging fm = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();
    fm.send(new RemoteMessage.Builder(SENDER_ID + "@fcm.googleapis.com")
        .setMessageId(Integer.toString(messageId))
        .addData("my_message", "Hello World")
        .addData("my_action","SAY_HELLO")
        .build());
```